# keep docker image in private docker registry in helm chart

Tags: package, kubernetes-helm, docker-image

I just need to know whether it is possible to keep a docker image which is in a private repository  in helm chart rather than keeping a reference to docker registry ?

UPDATED

What I am trying to do is pakage a deployed service in a kurbenets cluster using helm and use the service in a different kurbenate ckuster. To my knowledge, reference to docker an  image is stored in the helm chart. So what I am asking is, is there any possibility to pass the docker image itself rather than passing reference to docker registry in helm chart.

need your guidance.

Comment: what do you mean by "keeping docker image as data"?

Comment: Updated. Please check

Answer (score 1):

If docker image is in the private repo, you need to create [imagePullSecret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod) to store credentials to this repo. Then your packaged helm chart will know where to find this docker image and will be able to pull it.

Comment: Thanks for the guide Anna. does this means anyone outside the private repository can write to the repo by using imagePullSecret? or only they can pull the docker image from that private repo to thier cluster's docker registry.

Comment: ImagePullSecret is used by pods to pull docker images they're built on so I guess it can't be used to write the images. It's the same when you pull an image to your local machine for example, but only from a pod's point of view.